# AngularJS - Append html with ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs, append

```
$scope.selectNode = function(node){
    $(".withOptions").append('<li id="list_7"><div><i class="icon20 i-folder-open"></i> '+node.title+' <i class="icon16 i-arrow-down-2"></i><div ng-include="\'http://localhost/test/public/admin/theme\'"></div></div></li>');
}
```

This code add to my list this li item. But ng-include dosn't not compile from angularJS

What can i do...?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use a directive?

Comment: Do you have any example with directive?

Answer (score 2):

Possible that will work in this way:

```
$scope.selectNode = function(node){
     $(".withOptions").append($compile('<li id="list_7"><div><i class="icon20 i-folder-open"></i> '+node.title+' <i class="icon16 i-arrow-down-2"></i><div ng-include="\'http://localhost/test/public/admin/theme\'"></div></div></li>')($scope))
}
```

Comment: SyntaxError: missing name after . operator

Comment: Sorry, forgot "append". Also you will need to inject "$compile" into the function where you use this code.